# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray is null when try to convert String to Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I am trying to add an image from URL into ImageView. I have an encoded Base64 String that is decoded in order to add it at an ImageView as Bitmap. The encoded String has neither "data:image/jpg;base64, ...." nor "new lines" nor "=" at the end. Also, I convert 'http://' to 'https://' before start encoding. Despite the fact that seems right BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray still returns null.

Here is my code:

```
imageUrlString.replace("http://", "https://");
String imageEncode = Base64.encodeToString(imageUrlString.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP); //NO_WRAP in order to delete new lines
imageEncode.replace( "=", ""); //delete '=' at the end of encoded string 
byte[] imageDecode = Base64.decode(imageEncode.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageDecode, 0, imageDecode.length); //returns null
```

Comment: So you base64 encode an url. And then you base64 decode it back to an url. The same url. Did you check? And then you try to make a Bitmap out of an url!? That makes no sense.

Comment: i take utf-8 string(from server) and want it as base64.

Comment: No. Nothing comes from a server here. Reread my comment please as that is happening.

Comment: imageUrlString is a String which contains an image link

Comment: Yes. Indeed. That is what i thought already. So you have no image. And reread my first comment to know what you are actually doing. Your code makes no sense.

Comment: i understand what you are saying, and also i tried to use BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUrlString) instead of BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray but still result is null

Comment: decodeFile() cannot handle a http:\\ uri string. As decodeFile() will not download from internet.

Comment: finally, i used ImageLoader of 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader' and solved my problem. Thank you for your time